# gcc; arm64; aarch64; unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon'

Tags: gcc, arm, neon, arm64, linaro

I got compilation error:

> unrecognized command line option '-mfpu=neon'*
>   when tried to compile with -mfpu=neon flag.
>   Actually, any 'mfpu' options I tried failed. However in documentation this flag is mentioned, so it should be valid

What is wrong with this key?
How could I tell compiler to use NEON?

Linaro GNU aarch64 linux tools 4.8 are used.

Thanks.

Comment: Where in the documentation is it mentioned? [I don't see it there](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/AArch64-Options.html#AArch64-Options) (but I do see the relevant SIMD feature option...)

Comment: @Notlikethat See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux That's for the ARM backend, not the AArch64 one. Referring to the `-fpu` option [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RS_002f6000-and-PowerPC-Options.html) would be just as relevant as that ;)

Comment: @Notlikethat good catch, no such option for AArch64

Comment: @Notlikethat , Yes, it's. I looked in ARM-options as well. If you add your answer like answer not comment, I'll mark it as right. So you'll get credentials for help. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Advanced SIMD (aka NEON) is mandatory for AArch64, so no command line option is needed to instruct the compiler to use NEON.

If you want to enable auto vectorization optimisations so that the compiler automatically uses NEON instructions, then compile with `-O3` or `-O2 -ftree-vectorize`.

The AArch64 and ARM backends are completely separate in gcc. The ARM back end only targets the traditional 32 bit ARM instructions sets (ARM, Thumb, Thumb-2). This is in contrast to the situation with x86, where the 32 bit and 64 bit code generation is combined into a single GCC back end.

Answer (score 1):

Go to file /tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/BUILD, delete -mfpu=neon and you are good to go.
from:

```
NEON_FLAGS_IF_APPLICABLE = select({
    ":arm": [
        "-O3",
        "-mfpu=neon",
    ],
```

to:

```
NEON_FLAGS_IF_APPLICABLE = select({
    ":arm": [
        "-O3",

    ],
```